# How to send text to an application?

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to make an application, which reads the data from a serial port (on the serial port there is a barcode scanner plugged in), and then forwards it to an application. I can read data from serial port now, but i don't know, how to forward the read text, to an application, for example notepad. I tried to use SendMessage() API but it didn't succeed. Maybe i did something wrong.
Could someone help me, and maybe show some example?

Thanks,

kampi

Comment: Define "send". Why are you expecting the other application to be willing to **receive** data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304%28VS.85%29.aspx) or the newer [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). It allows you to simulate keyboard input.

Comment: Thanks for your help! SendInput is what i was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"Untitled - Notepad");
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)L"Hello!");
```

This will set the Notepad's title bar text to Hello. Of course, you can elaborate a bit to find Notepad's textbox control, or to find your own control in an application, or to find the control that has focus in the active foreground window (see GetForegroundWindow), but the idea is that once you have a hwnd of the window/control you want to set text, the above code should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send it to the Notepad, then it would be easier to save the text into a temporary file and then open it with the Notepad.  From a Windows application this could be done using `CreateProcess`.

On the other hand, if you in control of how the receiver application is working, you could use different approaches, such as: pipes, window messages, shared memory and some others. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28VS.85%29.aspx) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean *another* application, you should use one of [IPC methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method should be [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Can you use named pipes to send some text to an application which you don't have its source code? (like Notepad?)

Comment: The other application simply will not aware of your communication mechanism, it will not open the pipe, etc. This is similar as you would wish an application suddenly start reading data from a particular file that you created.